# Why am I getting connect_to localhost port 9190: failed. on my reverse ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling

Good day, I'm trying to create a reverse ssh tunnel with my university's remote server. I run the following command on my laptop:

```
< home >$ ssh -R 9999:localhost:9190 my_user@school_server.edu
```

I then open another terminal and run

```
< home >$ nc -l 9190
```

And on the terminal where I created the tunnel, after logging in, I run

```
< university >$ nc localhost 9999
```

When I try this on other computers, I get a connection without a problem between the remote server and the local computer, but on my laptop, I get

```
< university >$ connect_to localhost port 9190: failed.
```

When I run the nc command from the remote server.

I have both MacOS as well as Manjaro installed on my laptop, but the problem occurs with both, so it's not a firewall or OS network configuration problem. I've tried using a different network and the problem persists. I have just tried doing the exact same thing with my sister's laptop and it works, and my classmates can do it as well without a problem, so the remote server shouldn't be the problem.

Any idea of what might be causing an issue like this one? Thank you.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the non-reverse tunnel works perfectly.

More info:
Running with the -v flag outputed the following when trying to connect:

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 9999, originator 127.0.0.1 port 34590
debug1: connect_next: host 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:9190) in progress, fd=9
debug1: channel 1: new [127.0.0.1]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug1: channel 1: connection failed: Connection refused
connect_to 127.0.0.1 port 9190: failed.
debug1: channel 1: free: 127.0.0.1, nchannels 2
```

Comment: Try running `ssh` with the "-v" flag to print debugging info: `ssh -v -R ...`. Ssh will print more detail about why the connection to 9190 is failing.

Comment: Can mention the host where you run each command. _The other terminal_ is a bit confusing. Maybe something like `home:$ command1`, `unversity:$ command2`

Comment: sometimes `localhost` can mean `::1` (ipv6) rather than `127.0.0.1` (ipv4). Can you replace everywhere localhost with 127.0.0.1 and try again?

Comment: I have tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1, but get the same results. I updated the post with the verbose output and terminal notation to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

It is an order-of-operations issue. The SSH client is trying to pre-emptively set up the connection to port 9190 of the home computer right after the SSH connection is established, before the remote `nc` at the university system even starts. If the local port 9190 is not listening at that time, the remote forwarding set-up will fail.

So, you'll have to run your local `nc -l 9190` *before* starting the SSH connection, not *after* it.

There may be differences between OpenSSH versions in the exact behavior of the remote forwarding: newer versions might delay opening the local extension of the tunnel until something connects to the remote end.

Comment: So, the real order is following:
`local> nc -l -p 9190` then `local> ssh -R 9999:localhost:9190 my_user@school_server.edu`
then `remote> echo "I am here!" | nc localhost 9999`

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is from the point of view of `school_server.edu`. So it is trying to connect to 9190 on the remote.

I think you want it to connect to your local. Therefore (and this bit I am not 100% sure about) you should drop the host name. `ssh -R 9999:9190 my_user@school_server.edu`

Comment: I tried this, but still didn't work

Comment: What error message?

Comment: No error message, the command "nc localhost 9999" simply runs and closes immediately, as if I'd inputed any unassigned port.